# How to find matrix $A$ with linearly independent columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, matrix-rank

> Q: Find a $3\times5$ full rank matrix for which $\det(A^TA)\ne0$.

I know that if $\det(A^TA)\ne0$ then the columns of $A$ need to be linearly independent, but I cannot find a proper matrix. Any matrix I test has linearly dependent columns. Any suggestions?

Comment: There are no $3\times 5$ matrices whose columns are linearly independent, because the columns are then $5$ vectors in three-space.

Comment: @uniquesolution  : It is not the columns of $A$ that have to be independent.

Comment: The rank of $A$ is at most $3$, so also the rank of $A^TA$ is at most $3$; since $A^TA$ is $5\times5$ it cannot have nonzero determinant. Are you sure it is not $AA^T$?

Comment: @egreg yes I'm sure because pseudo inverse matrix A is asked to be calculated in the next step of the question (A^+ = (AT · A)^-1 · AT).

Comment: @uniquesolution yes you're right. Thanks

Comment: @user40085 Please read the OP's post. It says " the columns of $A$ need to be linearly independent" - I tried to explain to the OP that this is impossible. They answered " you are right", and kept it. What more can I do?

Comment: This is a misunderstanding of the OP. The columns of $A$ need not be linearly independent for the determinant of $A^T A$ to be zero.

Comment: As I explain in the answer below, depending on how you interpret the $3 \times 5$, the question has either no solution or plenty of solutions, including trivial ones.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ has 3 lines and 5 columns, then $\det A^T A = 0$. So it is impossible to find a matrix that satisfies your requirements.

On the other hand, if $A$ has 5 lines and 3 columns, this is pretty easy, you can take the identity matrix $I_3$ for the first three lines, and zero for the last two lines. Then $\det A^T A = 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're right.
 I think the question is wrong.